# Set array item inside an object in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

In AS3 is it possible to store the below for example inside an object:

```
{alpha: pobj.alpha, _vectSprite[<indexA>]: pobj.getSprite(<indexB>)}
```

Comment: You cannot use it in the generic object notation as above, but after the object is created you can use the square bracket notation to assign a new member: **O = {alpha: pobj.alpha}; O[_vectSprite[<indexA>]] = pobj.getSprite(<indexB>);**

Comment: What if _vectSprite is a member of a different class?

Comment: An **Object** is an associative array of key:value pairs where key is the **String** and value could be just any data. So, I don't really understand the question about *a member of a different class*. As long as you provide a valid key (some data will be forcibly typecast to **String** so you need to keep it in mind) you can read and write the value from the given **Object**.

Comment: I have Class A, which creates Class B. Class A passes that Object into Class B's constructor. Class B then unpacks the Object and Class B's variables are set based on the Object values; although now I want to set Class B's _vectSprite[0] from Class A - I want this to happen on Class creation, not afterward.

Comment: Send **{... spriteZero:pobj.getSprite(<indexB>) ...}** then initialize what you want inside the B's constructor: **_vectSprite = [O["spriteZero"]];** where **O** is the passed **Object** argument.

Comment: I think I do understand this, if that is the best option I have if I cannot directly use _vectSprite[i] within an Object then I will thank you now for all the fast responses. The last query I would have in regards to this topic would be if the code would also work in Haxe. I should have mentioned that in the start also. I am looking for **(identically written)** solutions that work in both AS3 and Haxe.